# capl how to change byte format to char fomat

Tags: format, capl

I want to change byte value to char value in capl.
Using MD5 the input value is char and the result value is byte
I want to put the result value into the input value
However, the format is different and cannot be used
I want to know the solution

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. Esp. show what you have done so far, which errors you get, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using arrays, you will need to define a second array of the correct type `byte` of the correct length. Then use `memcpy` to copy the char into the byte array.

```
char carr[5] = {0, -1, -2, -3, -4}; //char is signed!
byte barr[5];

memcpy (barr, carr, elCount(barr));
//data is now copied into barr, and can be used in a function that accepts byte arrays
```

If you are using normal scalar variables, you also can just us a normal cast:

```
byte b;
char c = -5;
b = (byte) c;
```

Comment: Also, you should never use your input array as output array, because you cannot predict what the function does and arrays are always passed _by reference_ whereas scalars are normally passed _by value_ thus your output data could be used as input data whilst the original input data would still be required.